# How to fix a broken MS Office (Project) Library reference?

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-project, ms-project-server-2016

One day while happily working away in MS Project I noticed that one of my custom formula fields did not work anymore. When I went to check the formula, it was gone (the formula, not the custom field). So, I went to go copy it from one of my other project files that uses the same formula. It was gone from there as well.

Strange. I asked a colleague if they could download the exact same file I was looking at and see the formula in the custom field. They did, and they could! Then we asked more colleagues to download the same file. Some could see the formula, and some could not.

When trying to manually add the formula back in, I get the following error for any of the ProjDateXX functions:

[image: Does not recognize the date parameter field]

When clicking OK, it highlights the date parameter "12d". For those who have this problem, it is the same for all ProjDateXX functions (date parameter isn't recognized).

So far, I have uninstalled and reinstalled MS Project, then MS Office and MS Project. Nothing fixes this.

The only clue I have to go on now is that the MS Project Library appears to be registered incorrectly, as seen here:

[image: Where is the version number? Should be a 16.0 here somewhere...]

The only other possible clue my colleagues and I have are that those of us who have the problem recently received Project Online P3 licenses in addition to the existing Project Professional licenses we already had. Why this would cause only one set of functions to stop working, or why that might cause the Project Object library reference to be missing the version number, are mysteries.

We are stumped and have no leads at this point. These functions are critical to our project analysis for some major customers; any help would be greatly appreciated.